# RDLC Local report viewer for ASP.NET Core v3.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I have a lot of reports with Microsoft Report. I have migrated all my other projects to `ASP.NET Core` v. 3.1. I want to keep my report in `rdcl` because are easy to update in Visual Studio.

In my solution I added

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms" Version="150.1404.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" Version="14.0.1016.290" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I noticed there are some warning in the packages. Understandable. The library is for .NET Framework not for .NET Core.

[image]

However, the project is compiling correctly. When I try to render the report, I have this error:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Looking around I found some libraries but none of them is working:

- [MvcReportViewer](https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer): the last update was 2 years ago and he was using the first .NET Core
- [AspNetCore.ReportViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.ReportViewer/): I can't find the project website or any example how to use it
- on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309797/rdlc-local-report-viewer-for-asp-net-core-and-angular2-0) I saw this post but it is quite up to date

Any idea? In alternative, is there a way to generate PDF in an Azure Functions?

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890414/can-one-use-reportviewer-control-in-asp-net-core