# How to run JAVA Desktop application as executable file on another machine

Tags: java, desktop-application

I want to run my JAVA desktop application to another machine as an executable file like .exe

I had already created .Jar file of my application but it not compatible for all machine.
Please suggest me how can i achieve this?

Comment: The `.exe` is what isn't compatible; the jar is.

Comment: 1. [Embed a JRE in a Windows executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2258932/2815219) 2. [How do I bundle a JRE into an EXE for a Java Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13996547/2815219)