# Unable to run .jre converted in .exe on other computers

Tags: java, exe

I used netbeans to create a calculator kind of app. I tried converting the jar file into a .exe file with launch 4j with a minimum .jre of 1.1.0 and 1.6_32 at some other time.

The app opened well in my laptop but it didnt open in  other laptops i tried deploying on. the message was "the application requires a minimum .jre of .1.1.0..." then next it tried opening browser to oracle website to download.

What can I do so that this app can run in other desktop and laptops without asking about minimum .jre requirement.

Comment: Nothing. The client computer requires a jre in this situation.

Comment: The other computer sounds  like it didn't have java installed

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996547/how-do-i-bundle-a-jre-into-an-exe-for-a-java-application-launch4j-says-runtime

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can't start on other computers because they don't have Java installed. This happens because the computer needs to be able to convert your .exe file (that before was a .jre) in instructions.